# disable other sounds in java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, javasound, audio

I wrote a program in Java using the pi4j lib to make sound whenever a (physical) button is clicked. This program works, but it now plays all the sounds interchangeably. I want that when you click on 2,3,4 or more buttons you only hear one sound.

This is the code I hope you can help.

```
public class ButtonSoundsProject{
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Toy has been started!");

    // create gpio controller
    final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

    // provision gpio pin #02 as an input pin with its internal pull down resistor enabled
    GpioPinDigitalInput[] pins = {
        gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_00, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN),
        gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN),
        gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN),
        gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_03, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN),
        gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_04, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN),
        gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_05, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN),};

    final ArrayList<String> soundList = new ArrayList<String>();
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound1.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound2.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound3.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound4.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound5.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound6.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound7.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound8.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound9.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound10.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound11.wav");
    soundList.add("/home/pi/Sounds/Sound12.wav");


    // create and register gpio pin listener
    GpioPinListenerDigital listener = new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
            // display pin state on console

            final int randomNum = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * 12);
            System.out.println(randomNum);

            System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
            InputStream in;
            try {
                System.out.println(soundList.get(randomNum).toString());
                String filepath = soundList.get(randomNum).toString();
                in = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
                AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(as);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    gpio.addListener(listener, pins);


    for (;;) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What library are you using that contains the `AudioStream` and `AudioPlayer` classes?

Comment: I found these methods in the standard Java libs.

Comment: I can't seem to find any Javadocs for them (though they seem to belong to the `sun.audio` package I think). I know how to solve your problem, but I can't advise you in regards to those classes since I can't play with them to see how they behave. My method is similar though, using the `javax.sound` package; is that sufficient?

Comment: What JDK version are you using (mine is 7)?

Comment: I will try it out, thank you for taking the time and indeed they are from the sun package.

Comment: Paul my JDK version is also 7.

Comment: Strange, I have no clue why I don't have that; nor why I can't find any Javadocs online. I do have the `sun.audio` package, but it appears to be empty. Anyways, I'll show you what I know. Answer forthcoming...

Answer (score 1):

*As stated in the comments, I can't give you advise regarding the `AudioStream` and `AudioPlayer` classes because I don't seem to have those in my JDK. Since my method is similar, I'll give you what I have, and you can hopefully take it from there.*

Basically, the solution is to stop and/or "mute" that audio clip. This is how I accomplish it using the `javax.sound` package.:

```
private Clip currentAudioClip; // Keep a reference to the current clip being played

public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {

    // Call this every time regardless.
    // If nothing is playing, this will do nothing.
    stopAudio();

    String filepath = soundList.get(randomNum)
    URL soundFileUrl = new File(filePath).toURI().toURL();

    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFileUrl);

    Line.Info lineInfo = new Line.Info(Clip.class);
    Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);

    currentAudioClip = (Clip) line;
    currentAudioClip.open(audioInputStream);
    audioClip.start();

    // Alternative if you want to loop continuously. Comment out the `.start` line to use this.
    // audioClip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

public void stopAudio(){
    if(audioClip != null){
        muteLine(); // A gotcha I discovered (see explanation below)
        audioClip.stop();

        // audioClip.loop(0); // if you chose to loop, use this instead of `.stop()`
        audioClip.flush();
        audioClip = null;
    }
}

public void muteLine(){
    BooleanControl muteControl = (BooleanControl) audioClip.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);
    if(muteControl != null){
        muteControl.setValue(true); // True to mute the line, false to unmute
    }       
}
```

In short, every time a pin state change event is fired, the previous audio clip will be ceased, and a new one should play. You shouldn't get any sound overlapping with this.

*Also note that this is a slight modification of my original code, so let me know if there are any issues*

**Note about the GOTCHA**

I wrote [a question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14406/13332) over on the [Raspberry PI Stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) about an odd problem I encountered. The problem was that I discovered my audio clip would not cease playing on command. It would continue playing for a seemingly arbitrary amount of time. The stranger thing is that I only observed this while testing the app on the raspberry; it worked perfectly fine on my local machine (and even on several other machines).

It is possible my issue is related to the "looping" of my clip; if that is the case, and you simply want the clip to play for its length and no further, you may not encounter that issue, and you can probably dispense with the "muting" code I included. However, if you do observe the same issue, at least you have a solution.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I wish I could give you an upvoe but my reputation ain't high enough. I will try it out and let you know if it worked. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user3460769 No problem. You should be able to now. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I had to only make everything static , totally forgot this at first I was like 'why do I get so many red lines' haha :)

Comment: @user3460769 Oh right because you're doing it in main, forgot about that. Mine was a separate class that I'd instantiate. Anywho, that's fine. Just don't make everything static when you're dealing with actual instances and such. :)

Comment: @PaulRitcher I actually did make everything static is this a problem?

Comment: @user3460769 Well if you're doing it from main, its not the end of the world. I'm guessing this is (or at least the start of) a simple application, or if you're just playing around, or testing to see how properly to do something, its fine. But if this component is part of a "larger" application, I'd encapsulate everything I showed in a separate class and remove the `static`. You probably understand what static does, and in your specific situation right now, unless you've got multiple threads or objects accessing the same value, I can't imagine any adverse effects from `static`.

Comment: @user3460769 Basically my warning was simply saying that if you place your version of the code I wrote in a separate class, you don't want to make everything static; you'd want them to behave in the regular "instance" or "object" fashion. I don't know what your skill level is, but many a novice java developers sometimes have the habit of making their entire application static for convenience, breaking pretty much every OO principle. So I was basically just sounding a general word of caution.

Comment: @paulritcher can you explain to me what Line is doing? The rest of the code is very much self explanatory. Thank you.

Comment: @user3460769 Its basically a factory pattern. The `Line.Info` describes some meta data; that particular interface is very high level so doesn't describe much beyond what type of [`Line`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html) class I want to use. The `Line` object returned from the [`AudioSystem#getLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) method is, in my case, some concrete implementation of a [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) object. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @PaulRitcher a lot of exceptions. Very weird. Does it have to do with the static? Or the Line object?

Comment: @user3460769 I have no idea, you'll have to show me what the exceptions are. Edit the question and plop them in at the bottom, is easiest way.